# Word Automation - Text, then table, then more text

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word, ole

I need your help,

I am trying to have text, followed by a table then more text however, the current output is table, text, then more text.

The problem:

[image]

The desired output:

[image]

The code in question:

```
function test() {

    var wordApp = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application")

    var doc = wordApp.Documents.Add()

        var sel = wordApp.Selection

    sel.TypeText("Text Content1")

    doc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(0.75)
    doc.PageSetup.RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(0.75)

    doc.Tables.Add(Range=doc.Range(0, 0), numrows=1, numcolumns=10)
    doc.Tables(1).Range.Font.Size = 9
    doc.Tables(1).Range.Font.Name = 'Arial'
    doc.Tables(1).Rows(1).Range.Font.Bold = true    

    doc.Tables(1).Cell(1,1).Range.Text = '#'
    doc.Tables(1).Cell(1,2).Range.Text = 'File Number'
    doc.Tables(1).Cell(1,3).Range.Text = 'Subject'
    doc.Tables(1).Cell(1,4).Range.Text = 'Branch'
    doc.Tables(1).Cell(1,5).Range.Text = 'Division'
    doc.Tables(1).Cell(1,6).Range.Text = 'Related Documents'
    doc.Tables(1).Cell(1,7).Range.Text = 'Current Status'
    doc.Tables(1).Cell(1,8).Range.Text = 'Assigned To'
    doc.Tables(1).Cell(1,9).Range.Text = 'Action Required'
    doc.Tables(1).Cell(1,10).Range.Text = 'Last Updated'

    doc.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior(1)


    sel.TypeParagraph()
    sel.TypeText("Text Content2")

    wordApp.Visible = true

    wordApp.Activate()

    wordApp.WindowState = 1
}
```

Comment: NB: this really isn't a VBA question (although it's probably best-answered by someone with Word-VBA experience)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're explicitly inserting your table at `Range(0,0)` (the very beginning of the document), hence why it's appearing above both text paragraphs.  Try:

```
doc.Tables.Add(sel.Range, numrows=1, numcolumns=10)
```

Then, after your `AutoFit` you'll probably need to do this:

```
doc.Range(doc.Range.End-1).Select()
sel.TypeParagraph()
sel.TypeText("TextContent2")
```